# Why does this batch script terminate unexpectedly?

Tags: batch, script

This batch script terminates when `%CHECKCONTINUE%` is given a null value by not inputting anything on line 13 (`SET /p CHECKCONTINUE=Okay to continue? (y/n):`), why is this?

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
TITLE Registry restore script
REM Restores registry settings and disables the cloud

SET %CHECKCONTINUE%=

:listaction
ECHO I'm about to...
ECHO 1.) Remove the registry data that specifies settings for TF2
ECHO 2.) Forcibly disable Steam Cloud.
ECHO.
SET /p CHECKCONTINUE=Okay to continue? (y/n): 

REM No?
IF %CHECKCONTINUE%==n GOTO exit
IF %CHECKCONTINUE%==no GOTO exit

REM Yes?
IF %CHECKCONTINUE%==y GOTO start
IF %CHECKCONTINUE%==yes GOTO start

REM Did they put something else?
IF DEFINED %CHECKCONTINUE% GOTO loop-notvalid

REM Did they not put anything at all?
IF NOT DEFINED %CHECKCONTINUE% GOTO loop-noreply

:start
REM Delete application specific data
REG DELETE HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Valve\Source\tf\Settings /f
REG DELETE HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Valve\Steam\Apps\440 /f

REM Disable Steam Cloud for TF2
REG ADD HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Valve\Steam\Apps\440 /v Cloud /t REG_DWORD /d "0x0" /f

:exit
ENDLOCAL
EXIT

:loop-notvalid
ECHO.
ECHO That's not a valid reply. Try again.
ECHO.
SET %CHECKCONTINUE%=
GOTO listaction

:loop-noreply
ECHO.
ECHO You must enter a reply.
ECHO.
SET %CHECKCONTINUE%=
GOTO listaction
```

Comment: What's with people writing batch scripts in all-uppercase? (Coding style question, I know, but...)

Comment: Habit from writing shell scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, on multiple lines you have:

```
SET %CHECKCONTINUE%=
```

This doesn't modify `CHECKCONTINUE` but uses its *value* as the variable name.

Change it to:

```
SET CHECKCONTINUE=
```

It would also be better if you moved it immediately above `set /p ...` -- this way you would only need it once.

---

`if defined` also only takes a variable name, so instead of

```
IF DEFINED %CHECKCONTINUE% GOTO loop-notvalid
```

you should use:

```
IF DEFINED CHECKCONTINUE GOTO loop-notvalid
```

---

Same applies to this line:

```
IF NOT DEFINED %CHECKCONTINUE% GOTO loop-noreply
```

However, it can be shortened to:

```
GOTO loop-noreply
```

If the variable were defined, the execution would never reach this line anyway (`if defined ...` above)

---

This is how I would have written it:

```
@echo off & setlocal
title Registry restore script
:: Restores registry settings and disables the Cloud

:menu
echo I'm about to...
echo 1) Remove the registry data that specifies settings for TF2
echo 2) Forcibly disable Steam Cloud.
echo.
set check=
set /p check=Okay to continue? (y/n)
:: /i means case-insensitive comparison
if /i %check%==y goto :start
if /i %check%==yes goto :start
if /i %check%==n goto :EOF
if /i %check%==no goto :EOF
:: On empty response, pick the safest option as default
if not defined check goto :EOF

goto :loop-invalid

:start
:: Delete application specific data
reg delete HKCU\Software\Valve\Source\tf\Settings /f
reg delete HKCU\Software\Valve\Steam\Apps\440 /f

:: Disable Steam Cloud for TF2
reg add HKCU\Software\Valve\Steam\Apps\440 /v Cloud /t REG_DWORD /d "0x0" /f

:loop-invalid
echo.
echo Not a valid answer.
goto :menu
```

Comment: If the script were run from inside an interactive Command Prompt shell, a plain `exit` would terminate the shell too, not just the script. Within a script, one should use either `goto :EOF` or `exit /b`. (`endlocal` is not necessary.)

Comment: It still terminates if you press enter with no input on `set /p check=Okay to continue? (y/n)` :(

Comment: @neurolysis: If you are talking about the rewritten version from my post, it's because I wrote it to. IMO, since there is a sensible default option ("no, don't restore"), pressing Enter should just choose that option. If you disagree, change to `if not defined check goto :loop-noreply`.

Comment: Well, that's the issue at hand. Even with `if not defined check goto :loop-noreply` as a check, it terminates...

Comment: @neurolysis: ...did you (re)add a `:loop-noreply` section? Also, try moving the `not defined` check immediately after `set /p`. And run everything from within a Command Prompt window, error messages _are_ helpful.

Comment: Ah, it's because you renamed the label. Fixed now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on grawity's great answer:

First, to answer your question:
Why does the batch script terminate when %CHECKCONTINUE% is given a null value?

The problem is, in line 16, you do this:

```
if %CHECKCONTINUE%==n GOTO exit
```

Since `CHECKCONTINUE` is "undefined", it evaluates to an "empty" string, so the statement on line 16 is actually doing:

```
if ==n GOTO exit
```

This is an invalid statement because there is nothing on the left hand side of the `"=="`. So, the batch script terminates when it tries to execute an improperly formatted statement:

```
C:\>script.cmd
I'm about to...
1.) Remove the registry data that specifies settings for TF2
2.) Forcibly disable Steam Cloud.

Okay to continue? (y/n): <ENTER key pressed>
GOTO was unexpected at this time.

C:\>
```

You would have a similar problem if someone types something that contains a space in it:

```
C:\>script.cmd
I'm about to...
1.) Remove the registry data that specifies settings for TF2
2.) Forcibly disable Steam Cloud.

Okay to continue? (y/n): Yes please
please==n was unexpected at this time.

C:\>
```

To fix this, you should use double quotes around the terms like this:

```
if "%CHECKCONTINUE%"=="n" GOTO :exit
```

This is necessary if the variables used could be "empty" or if they could have embedded whitespace, but it's just a good idea to always use double quotes when evaluating with `"=="`.

Note: Some errors (like the one above with `"if"` and `"=="` are "fatal" errors which will cause execution of the batch script to immediately stop. Other errors (like the one below with `"set"`), are "non-fatal" errors. For "non-fatal" errors, the statement with the error is NOT executed, an error message is shown, and the batch script continues to run starting with the next statement

Next, as grawity pointed out about this line:

```
set %CHECKCONTINUE%=
```

This doesn't modify CHECKCONTINUE but uses its value as the variable name.

Again, if `CHECKCONTINUE` was "undefined", it would evaluate to an "empty" string, so the statement is actually doing:

```
set =
```

This is also an invalid statement because there is nothing on the left hand side of the `"="`.

And these lines:

```
if defined %CHECKCONTINUE% GOTO loop-notvalid
if not defined %CHECKCONTINUE% GOTO loop-noreply
```

`"if defined"` (and `"if not defined"`) expects a variable name, not the value of a variable. If `CHECKCONTINUE` was undefined, `%CHECKCONTINUE%` would evaluate to an empty string, and these statements would actually be:

```
if defined  GOTO loop-notvalid
if not defined  GOTO loop-noreply
```

Here, `"if defined"` (and `"if not defined"`) is going to check if a variable named `GOTO` is defined or not.

Also, for these 3 lines, if `CHECKCONTINUE` was actually defined, `"set"` and `"if defined"` would operate on the `"value"` of the variable, rather than the `"name"` of the variable itself. So, if `CHECKCONTINUE` already had a value of `"y"`, then:

```
set %CHECKCONTINUE%=
if defined %CHECKCONTINUE% goto loop-notvalid
if not defined %CHECKCONTINUE% goto loop-noreply
```

would actually be seen as:

```
set y=
if defined y goto loop-notvalid
if not defined y goto loop-noreply
```

Example "script.cmd":

```
@set "CHECKCONTINUE="

@rem ## CHECKCONTINUE="%CHECKCONTINUE%" (undefined/empty). 
@rem ## 05: set %CHECKCONTINUE%=
set %CHECKCONTINUE%=

@echo This doesn't set the value of of the variable named "CHECKCONTINUE". 
@echo Since no variable name is actually specified, it is an error. 



@set "CHECKCONTINUE=yes"
@set "yes=something"

@rem ## CHECKCONTINUE="%CHECKCONTINUE%" and the value of the variable named "yes"="%yes%" 
@rem ## 17: set %CHECKCONTINUE%=
set %CHECKCONTINUE%=

@echo This doesn't set the value of the variable named "CHECKCONTINUE". 
@echo Since CHECKCONTINUE="%CHECKCONTINUE%", it sets the value of the variable named 
@echo "%CHECKCONTINUE%". No error is shown because the statement is valid. 
@echo It could have been a problem (well, at least a big annoyance) if 
@echo CHECKCONTINUE had the value: "path". The statement 
@echo should be: set "CHECKCONTINUE=" 

@rem ## 27: echo CHECKCONTINUE still has the value: "%CHECKCONTINUE%"
@echo CHECKCONTINUE still has the value: "%CHECKCONTINUE%"

@rem ## 30: echo and the variable named "%CHECKCONTINUE%" is now empty="%yes%"
@echo and the variable named "%CHECKCONTINUE%" is now empty="%yes%"



@set "yes="
@set "CHECKCONTINUE="
@set "echo=something"

@rem ## CHECKCONTINUE="%CHECKCONTINUE%" (undefined) and the value of the variable 
@rem ## named "echo"="%echo%". 
@rem ## 41: if defined %CHECKCONTINUE% echo Variable is defined.
if defined %CHECKCONTINUE% echo Variable is defined.

@echo This doesn't check if the variable named "CHECKCONTINUE" is defined. 
@echo Since it's "empty", it is skipped (well, there is nothing there to 
@echo "skip") and "if defined" is checking the next word (which is "echo"). 
@echo What's left is: if defined echo Variable is defined. 
@echo So, it checks if a variable named "echo" is defined (which it is). 
@echo Since "if defined" has checked a variable named "echo", it then tries 
@echo to execute the rest of the line starting with the word "Variable", 
@echo as a command. This fails and is an error. The statement 
@echo should be: if defined CHECKCONTINUE echo Variable is defined. 



@set "echo="

@rem ## CHECKCONTINUE="%CHECKCONTINUE%" (undefined) and "echo"="%echo%" (undefined). 
@rem ## 59: if not defined %CHECKCONTINUE% echo The-variable-is-not-defined.
if not defined %CHECKCONTINUE% echo The-variable-is-not-defined.

@echo Similar: Since "if not defined" has checked a variable named "echo" 
@echo (which is "undefined"), it then tries to execute the rest of the 
@echo line: "The-variable-is-not-defined." as a command. This fails and is 
@echo an error. The statement 
@echo should be: if not defined CHECKCONTINUE echo The-variable-is-not-defined. 



@set "echo=something"

@rem ## CHECKCONTINUE="%CHECKCONTINUE%" (undefined) and "echo"="%echo%". 
@rem ## 73: if defined %CHECKCONTINUE% echo Verify this.
if defined %CHECKCONTINUE% echo Verify this.

@echo Again, similar: Since "if defined" has checked a variable named 
@echo "echo", it then tries to execute the rest of the line starting with 
@echo the word: "Verify" as a command. This happens to be a valid command 
@echo but it also fails because of an incorrect parameter for the command. 
@echo The statement should be: if defined CHECKCONTINUE echo Verify this. 



@set "echo="

@set "CHECKCONTINUE=yes"
@set "yes="

@rem ## CHECKCONTINUE="%CHECKCONTINUE%" and the variable named "yes"="%yes%" (undefined). 
@rem ## 90: if not defined %CHECKCONTINUE% echo CHECKCONTINUE is not defined.
if not defined %CHECKCONTINUE% echo CHECKCONTINUE is not defined.

@echo Here "CHECKCONTINUE" is defined, but "if not defined" still doesn't 
@echo check if the variable named "CHECKCONTINUE" is defined. Since 
@echo CHECKCONTINUE has a value of "%CHECKCONTINUE%", "if not defined" is 
@echo checking if a variable named "%CHECKCONTINUE%" is defined (which it isn't). 
@echo This causes "if not defined" to proceed and echo the message when 
@echo that's probably not what was intended. The statement 
@echo should be: if not defined CHECKCONTINUE echo CHECKCONTINUE is not defined.
```

Running "script.cmd" you would get:

```
## CHECKCONTINUE="" (undefined/empty). 
## 05: set %CHECKCONTINUE%=

    C:\>set =
    The syntax of the command is incorrect.

This doesn't set the value of of the variable named "CHECKCONTINUE". 
Since no variable name is actually specified, it is an error. 



## CHECKCONTINUE="yes" and the value of the variable named "yes"="something" 
## 17: set %CHECKCONTINUE%=

    C:\>set yes=

This doesn't set the value of the variable named "CHECKCONTINUE". 
Since CHECKCONTINUE="yes", it sets the value of the variable named 
"yes". No error is shown because the statement is valid. 
It could have been a problem (well, at least a big annoyance) if 
CHECKCONTINUE had the value: "path". The statement 
should be: set "CHECKCONTINUE=" 

## 27: echo CHECKCONTINUE still has the value: "%CHECKCONTINUE%"

    CHECKCONTINUE still has the value: "yes"

## 30: echo and the variable named "yes" is now empty="%yes%"

    and the variable named "yes" is now empty=""



## CHECKCONTINUE="" (undefined) and the value of the variable 
## named "echo"="something". 
## 41: if defined %CHECKCONTINUE% echo Variable is defined.

    C:\>if defined echo Variable is defined.
    'Variable' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.

This doesn't check if the variable named "CHECKCONTINUE" is defined. 
Since it's "empty", it is skipped (well, there is nothing there to 
"skip") and "if defined" is checking the next word (which is "echo"). 
What's left is: if defined echo Variable is defined. 
So, it checks if a variable named "echo" is defined (which it is). 
Since "if defined" has checked a variable named "echo", it then tries 
to execute the rest of the line starting with the word "Variable", 
as a command. This fails and is an error. The statement 
should be: if defined CHECKCONTINUE echo Variable is defined. 



## CHECKCONTINUE="" (undefined) and "echo"="" (undefined). 
## 59: if not defined %CHECKCONTINUE% echo The-variable-is-not-defined.

    C:\>if not defined echo The-variable-is-not-defined.
    'The-variable-is-not-defined.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.

Similar: Since "if not defined" has checked a variable named "echo" 
(which is "undefined"), it then tries to execute the rest of the 
line: "The-variable-is-not-defined." as a command. This fails and is 
an error. The statement 
should be: if not defined CHECKCONTINUE echo The-variable-is-not-defined. 



## CHECKCONTINUE="" (undefined) and "echo"="something". 
## 73: if defined %CHECKCONTINUE% echo Verify this.

    C:\>if defined echo Verify this.
    An incorrect parameter was
    entered for the command.

Again, similar: Since "if defined" has checked a variable named 
"echo", it then tries to execute the rest of the line starting with 
the word: "Verify" as a command. This happens to be a valid command 
but it also fails because of an incorrect parameter for the command. 
The statement should be: if defined CHECKCONTINUE echo Verify this. 



## CHECKCONTINUE="yes" and the variable named "yes"="" (undefined). 
## 90: if not defined %CHECKCONTINUE% echo CHECKCONTINUE is not defined.

    C:\>if not defined yes echo CHECKCONTINUE is not defined.
    CHECKCONTINUE is not defined.

Here "CHECKCONTINUE" is defined, but "if not defined" still doesn't 
check if the variable named "CHECKCONTINUE" is defined. Since 
CHECKCONTINUE has a value of "yes", "if not defined" is 
checking if a variable named "yes" is defined (which it isn't). 
This causes "if not defined" to proceed and echo the message when 
that's probably not what was intended. The statement 
should be: if not defined CHECKCONTINUE echo CHECKCONTINUE is not defined.
```

Also, as an alternative to `"set /p"`, you could use `"choice"`:

```
@echo off
title Registry restore script
rem Restores registry settings and disables the cloud

rem "quotes" around variable name and value for set visibly shows what 
rem the variable is being set to and prevents accidentally including  
rem trailing whitespace in the variable's value.
    set "CHECKCONTINUE="

:listaction
echo I'm about to...
echo 1.) Remove the registry data that specifies settings for TF2
echo 2.) Forcibly disable Steam Cloud.
echo.
choice /c yn /M "Okay to continue"

set "CHECKCONTINUE=%errorlevel%"
if %CHECKCONTINUE% EQU 1 @echo Pressed Y && goto :start
if %CHECKCONTINUE% EQU 2 @echo Pressed N && goto :exit
if %CHECKCONTINUE% EQU 0 @echo Pressed Ctrl-C+n
@echo.

@echo Terminate batch job cancelled. You must enter a reply. Press n to exit.
@echo.
goto :listaction

rem The remainder of your code goes here ...
```

Note: the code at label: `"loop-notvalid"` is not necessary because "choice" won't accept undefined responses (y/n).

Also, the only way to get an "empty" response from the "choice" commnad, is if the user presses "Ctrl-C" to terminate batch job, and then enters N (No) to the "Terminate batch job (Y/N)?" prompt, indicating they DON'T want to exit. The code above catches that and prints a message then jumps (goto) to the ":listaction" label to re-prompt the user, so you don't need the code at the "loop-noreply" label either.

There is no need to "reset" errorlevel since the choice command takes care of that. And, it's not necessary to clear the `CHECKCONTINUE` variable because it is always set equal to `%errorlevel%` before the value of `CHECKCONTINUE` is examined.

By default, choice is "case-insensitive", so pressing "Y" or "N" is the same as pressing "y" or "n". This behavior can be changed by specifying `/cs` on the choice command line.